When to use 'from' with 'whence'?
As per the Cambridge Dictionary, 'whence' is a more curt form of 'from where'.
Yet, the very first usage examples reads:

It has been returned to the shop from whence it came.

(emphasis mine)
Indeed, looking at this older question, it is sometimes acceptable to combine 'whence' with an additional 'from'. (Pretty sure I have seen this usage in a different Shakespeare text than the one cited, so I have no reason to doubt this.)
The big question is now of course: when?
That is, are there

cases where using an additional 'from' would definitely be out of place
cases where using an additional 'from' is definitely "better"

?
(Presumably there must be a wide array of cases where it does not matter either way - no need to specifically mention these, unless of course those were all the cases, without exception.)

I assume that you know that nobody ever uses the term "whence" in modern language? "From whence it came" is used to invoke the idea of some epic i.e. smiting a dragon or some such. Using it without deliberately putting it into some fairytale context would make you sound very odd indeed

whence is just from where. People sometimes do use it. So, the previous comment is mistaken. It is also used in writing sometimes.

Note that Cambridge Dictionary does not call 'whence' curt. Curt does not mean shortened, but a negative, clipped, snotty form of communication. If you ask me for a small favor and I say "No I won't" without explanation, that's curt.

This question is similar to: Why need 'from' in "from whence his large yellow eyes glowed in the darkness"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@StuartF: That question is linked and motivated this one precisely because it provides no hint as to how to distinguish the two valid forms (with/-out preceeding 'from'). That I am interested in this distinction is even bolded in my question body. ... Note: It may well be that the correct answer is: "There is no difference" - but I do not know that and it is a different answer to whether "either form may occur" (possibly in different tones/voices/whathaveyou). Compare: "the prostitute" and "that hoe" - same meaning, both can be used, but they are very much not arbitrarly exchangable.

You could use from whence when referring to a location and omit  "from"  when whence is being used abstractly, i.e. when the "place" is not a physical place but an origin or source.

The countries from whence they emigrated were being torn apart by civil war.
Comparing the first and second equations n(m2-n2) =  p (m2-p2) whence we have (n-p)m2 = n3-p3


Have you any evidence for this rule, because I've never heard of it.

I'm describing how the word has been used when I've seen it used, which happens fairly often in academic writing, where it's not a rarity.  When the meaning is locative, from is an option (often used but not mandated though I'd say that the locative without "from" is obsolescent); with the abstract  sense "from" is eschewed.

For example: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=country+whence+they+came%2Ccountry+from+whence+they+came&year_start=1975&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2009&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=false    and  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whence+we+arrive+at%2C+from+when+we+arrive+at&year_start=1975&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2009&smoothing=3

@TimR : I almost wrote the "it does not matter" answer, now that no new input has arrived for a few days, but I stumbled over your comments down here, and faltered: In the context of natural languages, it is of course very valid to have different answers for different contexts, and I think "the" correct answer would have to contain three segments: in general no difference, among Shakespeare connoisseurs always 'from whence', in academic usage your rule. ... If you'd like to expand your answer to this scope, I should rather accept yours than write my own.

Whence is a fossil word that primarily survives as the phrase "from whence it came". In modern English, I would only use whence in that specific phrase, and only to evoke an archaic or fantasy feeling. In that sense, the answer is to always use "from whence".

(I'll leave "how to use whence properly in the archaic form" to somebody else, because I don't know. This question might also be suited for, or have a duplicate at, english.stackexchange.com?)

A Google Ngrams search for whence doesn't appear to reveal any obvious differences in usage between whence  and from whence, either in early or modern sources.

People opinions differ on what others might say. And this answer is an opinion.

This doesn't do much to answer the actual question; it answers a question that wasn't asked. It would probably be better as a comment, but its point has already been covered in the comments. Also: I don't know that this answer is accurate. There are definitely times that it's okay to drop the "from" ("Whence this sudden change of heart?"); I'm just not able to articulate whether there's any pattern to them.

@AndyBonner I can respect that (and I definitely encourage somebody to write an answer regarding the proper usage). But I do think that it answers "when should I, as an english learner, use 'from' with 'whence' in spoken/written english?". I would not suggest somebody use "whence this sudden change of heart?"

@Lambie yeah, I phrased it as "I would..." instead of a hard "it is only used..." for that reason. However, I do think it's a reasonable recommendation to be careful about whence. One common stylistic mistake english learners make is overusing archaic or vernacular phrases in the wrong context. "I'm working on the API, whence users' requests are received" sounds very silly.

I don't know users who overuse archaic phrases. English takes a capital e.

@lambie im not calling out any particular user of this site. im merely saying that understanding the definition of words without the context in which it makes sense to use them is something i see. its fine if you disagree; the downvote button is over there. but id suggest you provide a real answer if you feel mine isnt sufficient

I did not downvote your answer. A real answer to this can only be an opinion because how people speak is highly personal.

Kate wrote that ngram "doesn't appear to reveal any obvious differences." What does that mean exactly ?  At least from ngram it seems "whence" is quite a bit more popular than "from whence" in recent times. So there are often cases lacking the word "from".

I think "fossil" overstates the case but would agree that  99% of native speakers do not have "whence" and "thence" in their daily working vocabulary.

@Kaia: I feel I should remark that there really is not one such category as "an english learner". This Stack is meant to cater to all skill levels and directions of interest: "[...] speakers of other languages learning English", full stop. I do not think e.g. a pupil in primary school could care less about how to use yet another word, when they can make do with "where" just fine - but I, too, am a learner and would like to learn precisely that. Not how to "make it work" but how to "make it elegant" - both skills, but - especially in the context of language - almost in opposition to each other.
